# How to ensure that a 3D coordinate at Z=1 act like a 2D coordinate (using perspective projection)

Tags: 2d, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL ES 2.0: Mixing 2D with 3D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11766/opengl-es-2-0-mixing-2d-with-3d)

The title probably is not that clear but please help me out here. I am going to write a (mostly) 2D game using OpenGL ES 2.0 so if I have a vertex at (5,10,1) I want it to be drawn at the (5,10) pixel on the screen. But I can't use orthogonal projection because I'll still use some few real 3D objects on it to give a cool effect, and I want to preserve the perspective distortion on their vertices with Z > 1.

How should I set up my view/projection matrices to achieve this?

note: I am so sorry if this sounds like a noob question, but please take in account that I am a noob myself...

Comment: Isn't this helpful? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11766/opengl-es-2-0-mixing-2d-with-3d

Comment: omg I guess I have to learn how to use that search box right up there. Thanks that helps and is easier than I thought.